# NSArray object count strange issue

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I initialize a `NSArray` like below.

```
    NSArray *myArr  = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:name, empID, phone, email, website, nil];
```

`myArr` is supposed to have 5 elements. But `[myArr count]` shows only 4 elements.

**EDIT:**

One of the object `website` was nil in the array.

Comment: What if you initialiaze it with just four objects? Does it show 3?

Comment: Are you sure that all five of your objects are valid? If `website` is nil your array would only have four elements.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Darlington. You are right. The object website was nil. I stuck with this almost an hour. I didn't think this will end with this.

Comment: @Suresh I've added that as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that all five of your objects are valid? If website is nil your array would only have four elements.

You can't add `nil` objects to a dictionary. You *can* add a special `NSNull` object if you need to do something equivalent.

Comment: I was going to tell you to make it an answer. :)